# jQuery mobile input time with step

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, time

I would like to have a jQuery mobile input time with a predefined step for seconds. Is it possible?

For now I have:

```
<input id="schedule" type="time" name="open_hours">
```

I would like to add a parameter where I can set the minutes as step. For example, I just want the user to select only 00 or 30 minutes for every possible hour.

Comment: Possibly best off just using a radio or select element

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery UI's spinner for that and set step option to 30

http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time

They created a timespinner in that example, exactly what you seem to be looking for.